# Send a value for all HTTP calls in iOS, but don't include it in URL

Tags: ios, http

I want to send a value eg:ID for all http calls be it GET or POST or PUT. I don't want to send this ID as part of the URL. How do i achieve this ?

Comment: Put the value in a custom request header.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this way,
whereyour url is separate and parameters are sent by `NSMutableURLRequest`, then use `NSURLSession` to post to server
All your custom data would be set in `[request setHTTPBody:postData];`

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:httpMehod];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];
```